# Given Gaussian distributions of probabilities of a random variable, is it accurate to take every data point into account?

Tags: probability

I understand the phrasing of the question above is a little vague, but I couldn't figure out how to phrase it more accurately, so please feel free to fix it if you have a better way after reading this.

Here's the context: My department plays softball against other departments. Frequently, when we're fielding, someone else on the field will say to me (regarding the guy who's just getting up to bat for the 2nd time that game) "last time [meaning the player's first at bat that game] he hit over there, so move a little in that direction".

This is where my question stems from. For clarity, our default positions in the field are usually chosen so that they're at what you could safely call the "average" position of all the hits you typically see in softball, in general maximizing your chance of getting to a ball and fielding it.

Now, I personally think that it's *not* worth moving from this average position *based on one data point*, but my friend disagrees. He says that any data is better than no data, and that the one data point you have (where they hit their first time at bat) is worth taking into account, at least a tiny bit. I.e., if you're a center fielder and normally play directly in the center of the outfield, and they hit it very much to right field, you should move in the direction of right field, even if it's just a microscopic amount.

To me it's not clear that this one data point is more representative of where this person will hit in the future than it isn't; this is important because if it *is* representative, my friend is certainly correct and you'd want to move, at least a little. If it isn't, however, moving anywhere is moving you away from the typical "best" position.

My friend and I agree that we can assume that the position of all hits, from all players over all time, can be represented by a Gaussian distribution centered at some "average" position (call this the "total" distribution). Furthermore, for simplicity, let's also ignore the actual distance of the hit, and just look at the angle (from the line formed by home plate to the pitcher's mound, for example). Let's also ignore lefty hitters. We're also ignoring anything you previously know about the batter (like how he hit last season/game), or his batting stance, or anything.

Another important assumption we agree upon is that, in addition to the distribution of positions of *total* hits in the sport being a Gaussian, for an individual player, the positions of their hits are also a Gaussian distribution, but it can be centered at some place besides the average of all hits (for all players). In other words, the huge Gaussian of all hits from all players is formed from the sum of the Gaussian for each player (let's call this their "personal" distribution). So a player *can* have a personal distribution that's centered at 4 sigma away from the center of the total distribution.

So, given these assumptions, it seems like our fundamental disagreement comes down to this: a batter's first hit from the game lands somewhere in the distribution of all hits, let's say it's a 2 sigma event in this distribution. My friend thinks it's more likely that this hit was close to the center of that player's personal distribution, and therefore you should view it as a clue to the position of their personal distribution, and probably move towards there.

It's not as clear to me, and it seems like it could just as easily be a little bit of an outlier (in the total distribution), and the person has a personal distribution more similar to the total distribution.

Even more simply: my friend thinks an unusual hit means the personal distribution is an outlier, whereas I think it could just as easily mean that just that one hit itself was.

So is there a clear answer to this? The part I'm hung up on is how general the statement my friend is making is: it doesn't take into account how broad either distribution (total or personal) is, for example.

thanks!

Comment: In general, Gaussian distributions tend to be applicable for random variables that are sums of many small, more-or-less independent random components, in particular for small deviations from a "typical" value where there are many different factors contributing to such deviations.  While I have not examined the data in this case, I don't think locations of hits in softball would fit this paradigm very well, and I would be quite surprised if this distribution was well approximated by a Gaussian.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks for the reply, but let's assume that they are Gaussian distributed (or at the very least peaked and averaged at a certain value). Why do you think they're not though? What you said sounds very applicable to the position of softball hits: the way a batter stands and swings tends to put the "average" in left center, and things like connection with the ball, timing of swing, etc, give small deviations to this "default" location that can add up or cancel out. Are you disagreeing specifically with the Gaussian part or the peak/average part?

Comment: I don't think these are small factors.  The range is quite large (a 90 degree angle, not counting foul balls)

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I agree with you that the possible range is indeed large, what's your point though? People certainly do hit fouls and such, but I'm pretty sure the common knowledge is that hits (for a certain depth and the same handed batters) peak at a spot and probably decrease from there. It's possible it's a pretty broad peak, but the question still stands with that caveat then. Again are you more bothered by the Gaussian part or general distribution?